# _com_ptr_t::CreateInstance, HRESULT = ERROR_CANNOT_FIND_WND_CLASS

Tags: c++, com, windows-services, ado

I'm facing a problem with getting a COM interface loaded.

I'll explain the context a little :

i have a CredentialProvider (running at winlogon so) which does a loadlibrary + getProcAddress on a dll. This dll, in each of its functions, load the COM interface this way :

```
_ConnectionPtr con;
hr = con.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Connection));
if(FAILED(hr)
{
    _com_error err(hr);
    LPCTSTR errMsg = err.ErrorMessage();
    Log("hr = {%s}", errMsg);

    CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);

    hr = con.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Connection));
}
```

And it works fine.

However, after entering the userSession, a windows service finally loadlibrary/getProcAddress this same dll.

And when it tries to CreateInstance on the __uuidof(Connection), it fails with error "ERROR_CANNOT_FIND_WND_CLASS - Cannot find window class".

How should i interpret this error ? Actually, should i ?

Does someone have an idea of why it could fail with windows service while it succeeds few seconds before with the credentialProvider ?

Feel free to ask if any details is missing.

Thank you for any solution/clue/tip.

Comment: In my opinion, it looks like the issue most likely lies in implementation `Connection`, where the initialization of it fails with such error code, which gets, simply, returned to the user (you).

Comment: I do not implement Connection, it comes from msado15.dll which, i think, is quite safe. Also, the credentialProvider uses the same implementation, right ?

Comment: I am not familiar with the components, that you are using. I am merely stating my opinion, regarding the possible source of the error, based on information provided.

Comment: It doesn't seem stupid, regarding the error i get. But it's probably not the answer... I guess ! Thanks anyway

Comment: Running from a Windows service can be very different than running from a desktop. There's probably to UI in that service. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/hardware/design/dn653293(v=vs.85)

Comment: Hello Simon & thanks for the link. Hum, ain't winlogon also running in session 0 ? I'm currently trying impersonation to verify. I'll let you know the result

Comment: Seems impersonation ain't the solution either

Comment: Does your service call `CoInitialize` or `CoInitializeEx`?

Comment: You're a fucking genius. CoInitializeEx was failing in Service. Still don't know why Initializing through dll did not work though...

Comment: Please quote a couple lines of code with call to `CoInitializeEx` in your Service.

Comment: It's fine, i found the problem. I called it just before the getProcAddress and it works now. It was just a thread parameter problem as i had to choose COINIT_MULTITHREAD to be compatible.

Comment: `CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);` is my first line inside of my services WinMain.
My service also use a lots of COM and  ADO.

Comment: MyService starts at Winlogon but is useless until/unless i logon to a user session. I prefer not initializing a COM interface unless i really need it. I read it can be a bit heavy on performances. And also, my credential also initialize it. Is it fine to initialize it twice in two different threads... ? Who knows ? I can't find much documentation on COM "internal"

Comment: [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-coinitializeex) says you can call `CoInitializeEx` as many times as you wish. Just call `CoUninitialize` same count of times.